Window vsCode terminal seems to not recognize subfolders or node modules
I am installing my dev software on a new Windows 11 machine, I previously also used a Windows machine for development.
Using vsCode, I've installed git-bash, nvm, a repository with all of its node modules.
In package.json there is a script "local" : "scripts/ops/start.sh true".
If I call npm run local I get the following error:
> scripts/ops/start.sh true

'scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Windows powershell reports a similar error.
If I call scripts/ops/start.sh true directly in git-bash I get errors relating to ts-node not being installed, however it is installed in the node_modules directory of the repo.
nvm -v returns 1.1.12
node -v returns v22.11.0
These are as I would expect.
Similarly, in another repo, a script calling the node module next cannot find next.
Based on the above, the team and I assume that something is awry with my path, such that vsCode cannot find files not in the current directory that are not globally installed.
echo $PATH returns this string:
/c/Users/Computer/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Computer/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLIV2:/cmd:/bin:/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/c/Users/Computer/scoop/shims:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Local:/c/Users/Computer/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Any advice would be gratefully received. Starting dev on a windows machine is always exceptionally irritating.

VSCode uses Powershell by default on windows as the terminal. Powershell will not recognize a filepath to a script unless you start with "./"  instead of "scripts/ops/start.sh" try "./scripts/ops/start.sh"

On my previous machine and on this one, I had been using git-bash as my terminal.  I did try "./scripts/ops/start.sh" in powershell, but no great success there either.  I ended up just partitioning the new machine as a windows / linux dual boot.  Problem solved.
